# What components are needed for a look like this in Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

[image]

I'm trying to know which components in Material UI can help me achieve a block like this, or is it better to just use CSS

Comment: You could use Paper, Typography and MUI Icon components to achieve this kind of look

Comment: I agree with @PratikWadekar, I would either use `Content ` or `Paper` or even `Box` for the grey rectangle and inside `Typography` for the texts with different variants to achieve the bold text.

Comment: Yeah I mean it's totally upto you. For such a simple layout even plain CSS would have worked and importing all these components and then styling them also would be an overkill. What do you think?

Comment: @Akis, what's content? Also, wouldn't it be better to use Card over Paper? because from what iv'e seen i can't put icons on paper

Comment: Sorry @ucheozor i wanted to write `Container` (https://mui.com/material-ui/react-container/). Which one to use it totally depends of how the end result you want to behave based on the content but also the rest of the elements. Each one has different properties that you can use to achieve the desired result so that also means you don't have to customise it a lot.

Comment: Also to reply to @PratikWadekar, depending if this styling is only needed once then considering using plain CSS would be good, but if you reuse it then I would suggest to either use styled components and applying the styling in your theme for the `Typography`. If you are staring now with MUI i would strongly suggest to start using styled components as is a good thing to learn and as you go you will find your self that are very handy.